# Android Permission Issue android.permission.READ_CONTACTS

Tags: android, eclipse

All I am trying to do is read a contact off of my emulator and display it to the screen. I can't seem to resolve this error.  Both of my packages (com.msi.ibm.tutorial and .MobileServiceCallContacts) have the permission READ_CONTACTS set in their manifest xml files.

So any ideas as to what I've got wrong ?

Here is the error message from eclipse console if it helps, it's not helping me, but I'm a little rusty at this and completely new to Android development.

```
MobileServiceCallContacts]Starting activity com.msi.ibm.tutorial.MobileServiceCallContacts on device 
MobileServiceCallContacts]ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { cmp=com.msi.ibm.tutorial/.MobileServiceCallContacts }
MobileServiceCallContacts]ActivityManager: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.msi.ibm.tutorial/.MobileServiceCallContacts } from null (pid=-1, uid=-1) requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS
```

Comment: Could you post the manifest file?

Comment: OK, I tried to post the manifest file by cutting and pasting into this box, but I ran out of character space...I've been looking to see if/how to upload a file, but not having much luck...

Answer (score 5):

I added the following line of code:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
```

to just before the end manifest tag.

Removed any other code that mentioned this permission, stopped getting this error.

Comment: I don't know why my line of code is not showing up:

"<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>"

Answer (score 2):

Once i had this problem, I solved it by adding the permission declaration  to the activity itself

```
<activity  
android:permission="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"  
... />
```

Comment: I tried that and did not seem to help me.  I added it in all kinds of places to no avail...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but checking my manifest.xml I realized I was closing the wrong line of the read permission of the contacts, this should be the problem, so it works well:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```